# de-duplicate list but group parts of it

Tags: bash, shell, sort, uniq

I am compiling some access rules from failed logins and after some piping I arrived at this:

```bsh
cat <<INPUT | sort -k 3,3 --unique
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # demo
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # test
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # user
Deny from 133.142.200.152 # admin
INPUT
```

Just out of interest, I would like to keep the tried login names (the last field).
My test code would output:

```
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # demo
Deny from 133.142.200.152 # admin
```

I am looking for an output like:

```
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # demo, test, user
Deny from 133.142.200.152 # admin
```

or even better (because it would be valid `.htaccess` syntax):

```
# demo, test, user
Deny from 13.42.98.142
# admin
Deny from 133.142.200.152
```

**Note**:
The input is just how I made it now - I am not stubborn with it and can change it if it suits an elegant solution better. I'll accept also general answers how grouping in lists can be achieved in shell.

Comment: There have been various very good answers and I am sad that I can only accept one. I like the `datamash` solution for how concise it is. The `awk` solutions are a little more flexible. The stable sorting in @αғsнιη's solution helped me especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the order as how records have been seen (i.e, first seen first output), in any `awk`.

```
awk -v sep=', ' '
    { usr=$NF; sub(/[[:blank:]]*#.*$/, "");
      if(!seen[$0]++) ordr[$0]=++c;
      usrsRec[ordr[$0], $0]=dataRec[$0]= ($0 in dataRec?dataRec[$0] sep:"") usr
    }
END { for(recNr=1; recNr<=c; recNr++)
          for(data in dataRec)
              if((recNr, data) in usrsRec)
                  print "#", usrsRec[recNr, data] ORS data
 }' infile
```

Output:

```
# demo, test, user
Deny from 13.42.98.142
# admin
Deny from 133.142.200.152
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a task for `awk`.

```
awk -F'#' '
    { a[$1] = (a[$1] ? a[$1] "," $2 : $2) }
    END { for(x in a) print "#" a[x] ORS x }
' file

# admin
Deny from 133.142.200.152 
# demo, test, user
Deny from 13.42.98.142
```

Modifying the last `print` statement, you can achieve various output formats. Order of the records is not sorted by any key, and I assume you don't need it for your purpose.

In cases we need sorting by the key (as string, ascending), using GNU awk, we can add

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
```

before the `for` loop. Reference: [GNU awk array sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html)

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `datamash` to group by the first `#`-delimited field and collapse the second field:

```bsh
datamash -s -t '#' groupby 1 collapse 2 <<'END_RULES'
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # demo
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # test
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # user
Deny from 133.142.200.152 # admin
END_RULES
```

The `-s` option sorts the input data, which is not strictly necessary in this case since it appears to already be sorted.

Output:

```
Deny from 13.42.98.142 # demo, test, user
Deny from 133.142.200.152 # admin
```

Comment: Thank you for that gem: https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/ - I'll keep that in mind for general grouping